# valor atributo Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un `input` cuyo atributo tiene un valor recibido de la base de datos.
Cuando en la base de datos existen distintos valores, pues se recorre el array y se insertan en el `HTML`las tablas con sus `input` necesarios y los valores de sus atributos son los que trae la base de datos, cada `input`va dentro de una tabla. Sería de esta forma:

```
<table class="table-st" onmouseover="idEvento()">
<tr>
<td><input class="data-id" type="hidden" idvento='+arrayPartido[i].idEvento'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

De forma que si existen en la base de datos 3 registros en el campo idEvento, el `HTML` quedaría así (cada `input`iría dentro de una tabla distinta con igual clase):

```
<input class="data-id" type="hidden" idvento='+00001'>
<input class="data-id" type="hidden" idvento='+00002'>
<input class="data-id" type="hidden" idvento='+00003'>
```

El problema que tengo es que ahora quiero crear un evento en el cual cuando se pase el ratón por encima de cada tabla se muestre el valor de `idvento` en una alerta. Pero resulta que al pasar el ratón por encima de cualquiera de las tres tablas siempre me aparece el valor de la primera, en el ejemplo de arriba sería `idvento=00001`y yo quiero que aparezca su valor correspondiente según la tabla por la que se pase el cursor.

Adjunto el código `Javascript` que he utilizado:

```
function idEvento(){
    var id = $('input.data-id').attr('idvento')
    alert(id);
}
```

Cómo podría hacer para que al pasar el cursor hiciera lo que pido?
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo

Comment: en el método onmouseover idEvento pasa el parámetro de +arrayPartido[i].idEvento y prueba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sencilla es agregar ID de evento como `dataset` de la tabla y enviar la tabla como parámetro a la función.

```js
function idEvento(tabla) {
    console.log('ID de evento: ' + tabla.dataset.idevento);
}
```

```html
<table class="table-st" onmouseover="idEvento(this)" data-idevento="+0001">
<tr>
<td>Tabla 1</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="table-st" onmouseover="idEvento(this)" data-idevento="+0002">
<tr>
<td>Tabla 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="table-st" onmouseover="idEvento(this)" data-idevento="+0003">
<tr>
<td>Tabla 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Si aún quieres hacerlo con campo oculto, todavía debes enviar la tabla como parámetro para poder buscar el campo y, en lugar de usar un atributo no estándar, lo más adecuado es `value`:

```js
function idEvento(table) {
    console.log($(table).find('input[name=idevento]').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table class="table-st" onmouseover="idEvento(this)">
    <tr>
    <td>Tabla 1<input type="hidden" name="idevento" value="+0001"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="table-st" onmouseover="idEvento(this)">
    <tr>
    <td>Tabla 2<input type="hidden" name="idevento" value="+0002"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="table-st" onmouseover="idEvento(this)">
    <tr>
    <td>Tabla 3<input type="hidden" name="idevento" value="+0003"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```